# Unorder list (ul) font-size technique to prevent white-space

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a layout without px.
On the body I'm defining a font-size of 100%, in the ul element the font-size should be 0 to prevent a white-space between li elements and my li element contains a font-size of 2.5em:

HTML:

```
<body><ul id="social"><!-- li elements --></ul></body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
}

#social {
    font-size: 0;
}

#social li {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    display: inline;
}
```

The problem: The 2.5em are based on the font-size of #social which is 0. So the font-size of my li is 0 as well. I don't want to make it the dirty way: `</li><li>`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why is font-size of `ul` 0 ?

Comment: as said in the headline: to prevent white-space

Comment: Are you against commenting out the list-items? http://jsfiddle.net/nVS2c/

Comment: They are not necessary code. Or did you meant `</li><!-- newline and so on --><li>`?

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, that's a dirty way as well. I would love to see a css based solution.

Comment: It's too bad there's not a "close as duplicate" option for questions answered by css-tricks:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/h5Ef3/

Comment: You *could* leave off the `</li>` tags (@cimmanon beat me to linking that excellent `inline-block` article that mentions this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can also use the [`rem`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit) unit so that the `<ul>` & `<li>` font-size is relative to the computed font-size of the `<html>` element instead of inheriting the computed font-size of a parent. That may or may not go against your intended design though.

http://jsfiddle.net/nVS2c/2/

Support: http://caniuse.com/rem (not supported below IE 9)

Comment: That's an awesome solution!